# Find out which property changed in a Vue.js deep custom directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue with a deep custom directive, responding on changes in `v.item` :

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4xpbgq3/)

```
<div id='testdiv' v-demo="item">
  <div>
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{item.place}}
  </div>
</div>

Vue.directive('demo', {
    deep: true
  ,
    bind: function() {
      console.log('demo bound');
    }

  , update: function(newvalue,oldvalue) {
      console.log(newvalue,oldvalue);
    }
});

v=new Vue({
    el:'#testdiv'
  , data:function(){
      return {
        item: {
            name : "John Smith"
          , place : "Amsterdam"
        }
      };
  }
});
```

This is working. For example, when I change the value of `v.item.place` in the console, the directive is triggered, but `oldvalue` and `newvalue` are the same in the `update` event.

I need a way to find out which property has changed.

Any idea ?

Comment: do you want me to write a simple function that will solve your problem?. Because I dont believe  there is a way to do this in Vue atm.

Comment: Well, I really need this to work in a Vue directive. I think it's a bug that oldvalue and newvalue are the same. What kind of function would you use then ?

Comment: you have in wrong order your parameters in the directive handler. Your update function should have `newValue` and then `oldValue`

Comment: Ok I changed this, but they're still the same, so this seems like a bug.

Comment: I don't think this a bug - the `oldVal` and `newVal` both contain the same object because the object did not change, some property inside of it did.

Now, if Vue would set `oldVal` and `newVal` to the beofre and after values of the property that changed inside the object, you would have those values, but would still not know which property changed, either.

What you request is,  if anything, a new functionality, requiring new/additional parameters for the update function.

Comment: True, but if I would have the old and new object, I could at least compare them to see which property changed. Too bad, this is not supported yet.

Comment: one could make a simple function that compares the `Object.keys(OldVal) vs Object.keys(NewVal) `

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed property to create a new object whenever your item changes, and then use this computed in your directive:

```js
computed: {
    _item () {
      return Object.assign({}, this.item)
    },
  },
```

```html
<div id='testdiv' v-demo="_item">
  <div>
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{item.place}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Other solution would be to store you item in the HTML element (provided by the directive) and then when then in the update hook, do a manual comparation, something like this:

```js
function update(el, { value }) {
  if (JSON.stringify(el.__item) === JSON.stringify(value)) {
    return
  }
  bind(el, { value })
}
```