# Vue directive to detect changes in model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I write a Vue 2.x directive in such a way that it can detect changes in the model? I can only bind to the element and detect input, keydown, etc. But i can't detect when the model was updated. Is this out of scope for Vue's directives?

```js
 Vue.directive('text-validation', {
        bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
            el.addEventListener('input', function(){
             console.log('only gets called on input, not model updates');
            });
        }
    });
    
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  data: {
   text: 'testing...'
  },
  mounted: function() {
   setTimeout(function(){
       this.text = 'detected change';
    }.bind(this), 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="text" v-text-validation=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Answer (score 6):

Ah, I forgot what the `update` hook is for. I created a working snippet, that does what I intended - an update on model calls the update hook

```js
 Vue.directive('text-validation', {
        bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
            el.addEventListener('input', function(){
             console.log('got called');
            });
        },
        update: function(el, binding, vnode) {
         console.log('got called on upadate');
        }
    });
    
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  data: {
   text: 'testing...'
  },
  mounted: function() {
   setTimeout(function(){
       this.text = 'detected change';
    }.bind(this), 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="text" v-text-validation=""/>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I ended up setting up a watch() inside the bind() hook. Firing any kind of DOM native events from inside of update() was causing all sorts of infinite loops.

**Pseudocode:**

```
var modelExp = vnode.data.directives.find(d->d.name === 'model');
vnode.context.$watch(modelExp, function(){//do what i need}, {deep, true});
```

This was borrowed from "VeeValidate" project, ListenerGenerator.prototype._attachModelWatcher

Answer (score 1):

As @Bert pointed out - you can/could use watchers for that (if you do not need something more advanced - as central state / store Vuex etc.).

With watchers - it is very important to note that you can use them with "deep: true," that watches children inside objects;

```
watch: {
    myData: {
      handler: function (newVal, oldVal) {
        // we have new and old values
      },
      deep: true /* we will be notified of changes also if myData.child is changed :) */
    }
  }
```

State is more complicated but can be a saviour if app is getting more and more complex...

Found this usefull and simple demo: [Vue - Deep watching an array of objects and calculating the change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135188/vue-deep-watching-an-array-of-objects-and-calculating-the-change/41137008#41137008)