# Watch effect level deeper

Tags: vue.js, watch

I am trying to log whenever something changes value inside of the array, it only console logs items whenever I add or remove it, but how can I log whenever something has been changed in it? For e.g I'd like to see `item.Circle.position` to be console logged after it's changed.

And yes, I've tried watch with `deep: true`, but won't log it as well.

```js
watchEffect(async () => {
    await map.value.circles.forEach((item, i) => console.log(item.Circle, i))
})
```

```js
watch(async () => {
    await map.value.circles.forEach((item, i) => console.log(toRaw(item.Circle), i))
}, { deep: true })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135188/vue-deep-watching-an-array-of-objects-and-calculating-the-change

maybe this can help

Comment: Your `watch()` call needs to pass `map` as the first arg, as seen in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-deep-watcher?file=src/components/MapCircles.vue). You commented that it crashes when you try this. Can you fork the demo to reproduce that problem?

Comment: Is item.Circle reactive? As it was said in previous answer, it's incorrect to use watch without inputs. This isn't a common case, a workable example that can be debugged is advisable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to watch a copy of the array value, using the function syntax as the first parameter

```js
watch(() => [...map.value], async () => {
    await map.value.circles.forEach((item, i) => console.log(toRaw(item.Circle), i))
})
```

If your array contains 'deep' objects, you need to make a deep copy.  Here is an example using lodash

```js
watch(() => _.cloneDeep(map.value), async () => {
    await map.value.circles.forEach((item, i) => console.log(toRaw(item.Circle), i))
})
```

One final issue may be the way you mutate your data.  Try to use `Vue.set(...)` instead of directly adding properties such as `map['foo'] = 'bar'` or `map.foo = 'bar'` to ensure new properties are made reactive.